# speeding up some for loops in matlab

Tags: performance, matlab, for-loop

Basically I am trying to solve a 2nd order differential equation with the forward euler method. I have some for loops inside my code, which take considerable time to solve and I would like to speed things up a bit. Does anyone have any suggestions how could I do this?

And also when looking at the time it takes, I notice that my `end` at line 14 takes 45 % of my total time. What is `end` actually doing and why is it taking so much time?

Here is my simplified code:

```
t = 0:0.01:100;
dt = t(2)-t(1);
B = 3.5 * t;
F0 = 2 * t;

BB=zeros(1,length(t));  % Preallocation
x = 2;                  % Initial value
u = 0;                  % Initial value

for ii = 1:length(t)
    for kk = 1:ii
        BB(ii) = BB(ii) + B(kk) * u(ii-kk+1)*dt;    % This line takes the most time
    end                                             % This end takes 45% of the other time
    x(ii+1) = x(ii) + dt*u(ii);
    u(ii+1) = u(ii) + dt * (F0(ii) - BB(ii));
end
```

Running the code it takes me 8.552 sec.

Comment: You will probably get more help by tagging the proper language since the answer might be language dependent.

Comment: You might try replacing the innermost loop with the sum of a convolution (conv function), but I haven't worked through it.

Comment: Also, if you're bothering to preallocate `BB`, you might as well preallocate `x` and `u` as well.

Comment: @JoeSerrano I tried using the `conv` function, but it is actually much slower than my current approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the inner loop, I think:

```
for ii = 1:length(t)
    for kk = 1:ii
        BB(ii) = BB(ii) + B(kk) * u(ii-kk+1)*dt;    % This line takes the most time
    end                                             % This end takes 45% of the other time
    x(ii+1) = x(ii) + dt*u(ii);
    u(ii+1) = u(ii) + dt * (F0(ii) - BB(ii));
end
```

So `BB(ii)` = `BB(ii)` (zero at initalisation) + `sum` for `1 to ii` of  `BB(kk)* u(ii-kk+1).dt`

**but** `kk = 1:ii`, so for a given `ii`, `ii-kk+1` →　`ii-(1:ii) + 1` → `ii:-1:1`

So I think this is equivalent to:

```
for ii = 1:length(t)

    BB(ii) = sum(B(1:ii).*u(ii:-1:1)*dt);
    x(ii+1) = x(ii) + dt*u(ii);
    u(ii+1) = u(ii) + dt * (F0(ii) - BB(ii));

end
```

It doesn't take as long as 8 seconds for me using either method, but the version with only one loop is about 2x as fast (the output of BB appears to be the same).

Comment: Is the `ii:-1:1` just reversing the order of index?
But other than that, it is quite brilliant!

Comment: Yep - it's the equivalent of just flipping it. There may be more elegant ways of writing it, granted. ;)

Comment: fliplr or flipud flip vectors. These functions may be more readable but seem to take about 3x as long

Answer (score 1):

Is the sum loop of `B(kk) * u(ii-kk+1)` just `conv(B(1:ii),u(1:ii),'same')`

Answer (score 0):

The best way to speed up loops in matlab is to try to avoid them. Try if you are able to perform a matrix operation instead of the inner loop. For example try to break the calculation you do there in small parts, then decide, if there are parts you can perform in advance without knowing the results of the next iteration of the loop.

to your secound part of the question, my guess:: The `end` contains the check if  the loop runs for another round and this check by it self is not that long but called 50.015.001 times!